# Get all entries from Log where Key is never

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have three tables. All three of them have a Primary Key. One table is like an enumeration with events. The second table provides some information about a car.

So every time I change the status of the car I put a log in the third table. The third table provides the `carId` and the `eventId`.

So how to get all cars that never had, for example, event 6.

Comment: Add some sample table data and the expected result. (As formatted text, not images.) Also show us your current query attempt.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know the table structures, but I think you are looking something like this

```
select * from 
CarInformation C
inner join Event E on C.eventId = E.Id
WHERE 
NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM LogTable WHERE carId = C.id AND eventId = C.eventId)
```

Comment: This is exactly what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Table 1 - Car_Details(Carid,car_name)
table 2 - Event_details(eventid,event_name)
table 3 - car_event_details(carid,eventid)

```
select distinct carid,car_name 
from car_details c,
event_Details e,
car_event_details ce
where c.carid = ce.carid
and e.eventid = ce.eventid
and ce.eventid <> 6;
```

I have used distinct as each time status changes a log is inserted so there may be multiple entries in log table if same car has gone through same status multiple times.